# "Time to" or "time for"?

Tags: vocabulary

`"Time to"` vs. `"time for"`

Excluding fixed expression like `from time to time`, are both forms acceptable, and do they have the same meaning?

`It's time to buy a new TV.` or `It's time for buying a new TV.`

`It's time to make a coffee break`,`It's time for making a coffee break`

`It's time to a coffee break`,`It's time for a coffee break`

Are all pairs right and equivalent?

Answer (score 6):

You use **to** before a verb and **for** before a noun.

"It's **time to acquire** a new TV" = "It's **time for the acquisition** of a new TV". Alternatively, you can use "It's **time we acquired** a new TV"

Comment: I did a comment along these lines and then deleted it because i didn't think "buying a new TV" was a noun.  Is it?

Comment: Nah, that's why I used acquire and acquisition. you can say "This new TV was a good buy" though

Comment: Oh yeah, i just realised that it's not correct to say "It's time for buying a new tv".  Doh.

Comment: "Buying a new TV" is a noun. It is the object of the preposition "for." This is why it can be replaced by a pronoun. "It's time for buying a new TV" can be said "It's time for it." Not that I would say it like this, but it's not wrong.

Comment: If this is indeed correct, then I have never seen it used like that, and it sounds really strange, I would advise against using it.

Comment: @MorganFR It's not unheard of. Consider this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time+for+paying+attention&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctime%20for%20paying%20attention%3B%2Cc0) on *time for paying attention*. If you add the phrase *time to pay attention*, the *for* version gets swamped, but it's in use.

Comment: the ngram (where for gets completely crushed) kinda proves that "to pay attention" is the go to. Such a small amount might just prove that some people make the same mistake as Quora, like foreigners for instance. I know for a fact French people often, if not always, miss use that expression. But then again, it might be correct, but not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

With your first example you correctly establish that

- for the 'time to' variant you use the 'to ..' form (infinitive)
- and for the 'time for' variant you should use the '..-ing' form (gerund).

Both these forms are correct and have roughly the same meaning. I refer you to [this article](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/part_1.htm) about infinitives versus gerund for a description of the similarities and subtle differences between them. Main point I take is this:

"Both gerunds and infinitives can be used as the subject or the complement of a sentence. However, as subjects or complements, gerunds usually sound more like normal, spoken English, whereas infinitives sound more abstract."

Your second example is wrong, but that's more because you don't 'make a coffee break', you 'take' one or 'have' one. So in your third example the correct first form would be 'It's time to take a coffee break'.

Comment: Too bad there is no mention of a "for +ing" example in your source, that might have settled the discussion :D